# gnome 3 application menu silent on mouse click!

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel

i have installed gnome 3 DE on my desktop over my ubuntu 16LTS that came with Unity. everything was fine suddenly when i realised that the application menu isnt respponding to mouse clicks, whereas other things like date,clock,sound,logout etc are responding fine.if i click any of the other and hover my mouse over applications, it opens, but not when clicked seperately.i closed the applications menu and installed the ark menu to see the change but the problem persists! please help with this annoying little problem!